# Creating custom page with data from database in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a wordpress website with some information on the page with displaying data from the database. So, I have the home page which has some information to display. I want to display the data right below this information on the home page. So, I performed the following steps:

```
1) Created a block on the new page and enter the information for the home page
2) Inserted data on the database
3) Created a publications.php page and saved it on the themes folder as Publication template
4) Installed InsertPages plugin on wordpress
5) Created a new page with title and template set as Publication
6) Then, added a new block below the block from 1) in the Home page
```

The code looks like below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Publications
 * The template used for displaying publications 
 */
?>

<div class="pubications">
    <ul class="collection">
        <?php
            global $wpdb;
                $publications = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `cidhi_publications` ORDER by Year DESC LIMIT 12;");
             <div class="content">
            foreach($publications as $publication){
                echo "<li class='collection-item avatar'><a href='https://doi.org/".$publication->doi."'>";
                echo "<img src='/cidhi/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/".$publication->image_name."' alt='' class='circle'>";    
                echo "<span class='title'>".$publication->Title."</span>";
                echo "<p>".$publication->Authors."</p>";
                echo "<a href='#!' class='secondary-content'>".$publication->Year."</a>";
                echo "</a></li>";
            }
        </div>
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I only open the page as follows: `http://localhost://wp/publications`, it shows the data but without the theme formatting but only as plain HTML.

But, if I open the main home page, where this page is inserted to the home page, I only see the title not the content. I also checked the settings in "InsertPages" Plugin and made sure that "Display" section has "All" selected

This is the first time I'm working on wordpress so any direction can be very helpful. I"m using the most recent version of wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Your Publications template needs to call the WordPress header and footer files.

So, above your HTML, add:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

And below it, add:

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```